# How can function recv on mpsc take a reference and return ownership?

Tags: rust

Here's an example of message based communication using `mpsc`.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::
let (tx, rx) = channel();
thread::spawn(move|| {
    tx.send(10).unwrap();
});
assert_eq!(rx.recv().unwrap(), 10);
```

Heres how the `recv` isdefined.

```
pub struct Receiver<T> { /* fields omitted */ }
pub fn recv(&self) -> Result<T, RecvError>
```

How can a method taking reference return ownership of `T` where  `T` is not bound by `Copy` or `Clone`. Doesnt it break rust ownership rules? I took  a look into source and I  see many `unsafe` in it. Is it a way of making it safe with unsafes?

Comment: Well, when you receive something it is owned, it doesnt matter if it is a reference or whatever. T is just the generic there.

Comment: The `recv` function takes  ` &Receiver<T>`. It only owns the reference. But it still can return `T` even if `T: Clone` is not implemented ?

Comment: But it is the reference to the Receiver, not to what it will come in the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's consider a `Vec`.  With only a (mutable) borrow of a `Vec` instance, we can move a `T` into the vector with [`Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push) and move it out again with [`Vec::pop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop).  `T` does not need to be copied or cloned: the same `T` that was pushed onto the vector is popped back out again (ownership was transferred to/from the `Vec`).

Now let's consider a `Cell`.  With only an immutable borrow of a `Cell` instance, we can move a `T` into the cell with [`Cell::set`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.set) and move it out again with [`Cell::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.take).  `T` does not need to be copied or cloned: the same `T` that was set into the cell is taken back out again (ownership was transferred to/from the `Cell`).

Of course, mutating something (in this example, our `Cell` instance) through an immutable borrow does ultimately require its implementation to make use of `unsafe` code, but that's fine *provided it upholds Rust's safety invariants* (and the `std` library authors are very careful to do that)—this is, after all, the *purpose* of `unsafe` code: to opt out of some compiler-enforced safety checks when we wish to take responsibility for upholding those invariants ourselves (e.g. because we have some deeper insight into the runtime state of our code than the compiler).

An `mpsc` is no different.  `T` is moved into the channel in [`Sender::send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.send); and is moved out again in [`Receiver::recv`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv).  The `T` does not need to be copied or cloned: the same `T` that was sent is received out the other end (ownership was transferred to/from the `mpsc`).

Comment: Yes. `pop` is a better example. I am still getting comfortable with the ownership system. But it does mean all such implementation would NEED an unsafe implementation deep down right? Somewhere a reference to a type that's not owned by the function needs to be dereferenced.  But we can safely implement it with unsafe without breaking rust principles. Am I right?

Comment: @raj: I've edited the answer to elaborate a little further. Mutating memory does not require any `unsafe` code provided you have either *ownership* or a *mutable borrow* of it (this is because, in both cases, you are guaranteed to have *exclusive access* to that memory—thus ensuring that no other access is simultaneously occurring through some other alias). Only when the mutation needs to occur with neither ownership nor a mutable borrow is `unsafe` code required: and then it is up to *the author* to provide the exclusivity guarantees that the compiler would otherwise have enforced.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a function that takes ` &mut Type<T> `  and return the ownership type `T` that doesnt use `unsafe` underneath ?

Comment: @raj: The returning of an owned `T` is completely orthogonal to the types of the function's arguments: for example, `fn foo() -> T` is entirely possible despite there being no arguments at all, e.g. by merely instantiating a new `T`.  It's the modifying of something that is only immutably borrowed (whether its type is parameterised by `T` or not) that requires `unsafe`, irrespective of the function's signature/return type.

Comment: @raj: Reflecting on this a little further, I think you may be right that *moving* ownership out of something might always depend upon `unsafe` code if you dig low enough—though I don't think there's anything about the language *per se* that requires it.